# Aggregate sum over a particular ID value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, aggregate

Say, I have 3 columns in my table :

```
---------------
name                 | ID  | Amt
ABC                  |  1  | 500
ABC                  |  1  | 650
XYZ                  |  2  | 700
XYZ                  |  2  | 550
DEF                  |  3  | 200
```

how can I get an output where the amount is aggregated for each ID, i.e., 
ABC gives 1150, XYZ 1250 and DEF 200?

Answer (score 1):

You want a group by, with what sounds like a sum from your example:

```
Select Name, ID, sum(amt) as TotalAmt
from MyTable
Group by Name, ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,SUM(Amt) FROM [table] GROUP BY name
```

or, if you want to display name and ID

```
SELECT name,ID,SUM(Amt) OVER (PARTITION BY name) FROM [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using a simple `group by` statement:

```
select name,
       id,
       sum(amt) as agg_sum
from total
group by name,id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c13f/1/0)